# Consumer group is not working with .net client

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, consumer

I am using Kafka .Net client and trying to consume records with multiple consumers.But getting same message in all the consumers.I have set consumer group also for my topic but does not work.I am using kafka 0.9.0.Is there any specific setting so that it will work with multiple consumer?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code. If you set the **same** group name for all consumers, it should work as you intent AFAIK.

Comment: Hi Matthias,Please check link to download my code https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s22gqy5pl6je8k2/AABmjmN8T2B7swYGjDNNfj-Ha?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question an add your code there... (or the relevant parts)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937786/create-multiple-consumer-group-for-multiple-topic

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/Microsoft/CSharpClient-for-Kafka

You can find some sample code I wrote here.
[Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937786/create-multiple-consumer-group-for-multiple-topic/38429111#38429111)